# Get list of products on current category page in custom block magento 2.3

Tags: magento2, magento2.3, product-list, category-products, custom-block

I want to get the list of products currently visible on category page in a custom block. 
I tried using

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<page layout="1column" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <body>
        <referenceContainer name="content">
                <block class="Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\ListProduct" name="mycustomblock" template="MyModule_Schema::product/customlist.phtml" before="-" />
        </referenceContainer>
    </body>
</page>
```

But when I use this the sorting on category page does not work.

There are no logs except on system.log

```
You cannot define a correlation name 'review_summary' more than once [] []
```

I have also tried using this block using blockManager and also tried extending the block. Sorting does not work whenever I use this.

Is there any other way to get products without using that block?

Comment: Have you found the solution ?

Answer (score 0):

Check below code

create a block to load product collection and pass data to a template.

File: **Myvendor\Mymodule\Block\CatProductCollection.php;**

```
<?php
/**
 * @copyright DEVIMAGE
 *
 * @see PROJECT_LICENSE.txt
 */
namespace Myvendor\Mymodule\Block;

use Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template;
use Magento\Catalog\Model\categoryFactory;
use Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template\Context;
use Magento\Catalog\Model\ResourceModel\Product\CollectionFactory;
use Magento\Framework\Registry;
use Magento\Catalog\Model\Category;
use Magento\Catalog\Model\Product\Visibility;
use Magento\Catalog\Model\Product\Attribute\Source\Status;
use Magento\Catalog\Model\CategoryRepository;
use Magento\Framework\ObjectManagerInterface;

/**
 * Class CatProductCollection
 */
class CatProductCollection extends Template
{
    /** @var Registry  */
    private $_registry;

    /** @var categoryFactory  */
    private $_categoryFactory;

    /** @var CollectionFactory  */
    protected $_productCollectionFactory;

    /** @var Category  */
    protected $_category;

    /** @var **/
    protected $categoryRepository;

    protected $_objectManager = null;
    /**
     * CatProductCollection constructor.
     * @param Context $context
     * @param CollectionFactory $productCollectionFactory
     * @param Registry $registry
     * @param Category $category
     * @param categoryFactory $categoryFactory
     * @param array $data
     */
    public function __construct(
        Context $context,
        CollectionFactory $productCollectionFactory,
        Registry $registry,
        Category $category,
        categoryFactory $categoryFactory,
        CategoryRepository $categoryRepository,
        ObjectManagerInterface $objectManager,
        array $data = []
    ) {
        parent::__construct($context, $data);

        $this->_registry = $registry;
        $this->_categoryFactory = $categoryFactory;
        $this->_productCollectionFactory = $productCollectionFactory;
        $this->_category = $category;
        $this->categoryRepository = $categoryRepository;
        $this->_objectManager = $objectManager;
    }

    /**
     * @return array (product)
     */
    public function getCategoryProductCollection()
    {
        //get current category ID
        $category_load = $this->_registry->registry('current_category');
        $categoryId = $category_load->getId();
        //load product collection of category id wise
        $category_product_collection = $this->_categoryFactory->create()->load($categoryId);
        $collection = $this->_productCollectionFactory->create();
        $collection->addAttributeToSelect('*');
        $collection->addCategoryFilter($category_product_collection);
        $collection->addAttributeToFilter('visibility', Visibility::VISIBILITY_BOTH);
        $collection->addAttributeToFilter('status',Status::STATUS_ENABLED);

        return $collection;
    }


}
```

Then, override **catalog_category_view.xml** in your custom module and add the below code in this layout.

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<!--
/**
 * Copyright © 2020 DEVIMAGE. All rights reserved.
 */
-->
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" layout="1column" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <body>
        <referenceContainer name="content">
            <block class="Myvendor\Mymodule\Block\CatProductCollection" name="catprocollection" template="Myvendor_Mymodule::customlist.phtml" />
        </referenceContainer>         
    </body>
</page>
```

Then show the collection in template file

```
<?php
/**
 * @copyright DEVIMAGE
 *
 * @see PROJECT_LICENSE.txt
 *
 * @var Myvendor\Mymodule\Block\CatProductCollection $block 
 */

$catPCollection  = $block->getCategoryProductCollection();
foreach ($catPCollection as $product):
        echo $product->getId();
endforeach;
```

I hope this will help you.

Comment: This gives a collection of Products, not the products displayed on current page.

Comment: I have to get current category id and get all product collection and show in current page where you want me just print product id not all data